# How to change thread pool configuration in Apache CXF

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I have created a service which is using camel and cxf. I am trying to increase the performance and utilization of CPU, for this I have configured the threadPoolProfile for Camel EIP's and multiple thread pools are getting created. How can I configure similarly for CXF thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Karaf container as explained in the [**discussion link**](http://users.cxf.apache.narkive.com/VM6jalOb/no-bean-named-cxf-is-defined-when-trying-to-configure-jetty) you can configure the pool just by adding a *.cfg file.

Ex:

**File to be added :** $KARAF_HOME/etc/org.apache.cxf.http.jetty-8017.cfg

**File content:**

```
port=8017

threadingParameters.minThreads=10

threadingParameters.maxThreads=50
```

Even if Karaf is not in use, below spring configuration can be used to achieve the same :

```
<httpj:engine-factory bus="online-tests" >
<httpj:engine port="8017" >
<httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="10" maxThreads="50" />
</httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>
```